# scala.io.Source object empty after accessing with mkString?

Tags: scala

I just tried out the functionalities of `scala.io.{Source, BufferedSource}`. But after running `mkString` method the `scala.io.BufferedSource` instance is an empty iterator. My code looks like this:

```
val myFile = Try { Source.fromFile("myFile.tmp") }

println(myFile) // prints: "Success(non-empty iterator)"

val content: Option[String] = myFile match {
  case Success(file) => Some(file.mkString)
  case Failure(exception) => None
}

println(myFile) // prints: "Success(empty iterator)"
```

Is the `BufferedSource` instance affected (emptied)? In the scala documentation it is not mentioned: [scala.io.BufferedSource](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.BufferedSource@mkString:String)

I'm new to the Scala-API so maybe I missed something for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BufferedSource` class implements the [TraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) trait, the documentation for which isn't exactly the most helpful: "A template trait for collections which can be traversed either once only or one or more times."  But in the case of `BufferedSource`, it looks like it is truly traversable only once.

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedSource` is subclass of `Iterator`. Method `mkString` iterate over current instance and make string representation of it. So after calling `mkString` you receive empty iterator.